How to use magic function in PyCharm project?
My program uses magic function %matplotlib inline but for some reason, PyCharm treats this lane as a error.


On JupyterLab everything was great, now I am trying to build the whole program and I don't know what the issue is here.

My PyCharm version == 2022.3.1
My matplotlib version == 3.9.1
My python version == 3.9.13


You don't.
IPython or Jupyter magic commands are not part of Python syntax, and they can't exist in .py files.
You can open .ipynb files (IPython/Jupyter notebooks) in PyCharm, where magic commands might work (as they are interpreted by IPython, not Python), but those are not Python files.
